# Setting an embeded font in a datagridview combobox column (Winform)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Been looking all over for this but can't find anything. Is it possible to set an embeded font for a datagridview combobox column? I embded a font (engineering symbols) and I can assign it to a regular combobox just fine. Here is the code for that:

```
private void AllocFont(Font f, Control c, float size)
    {
        FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
        c.Font = new Font(ff, size, fontStyle);
    }
```

And I use it like this:

```
private void Inspection_report_builder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadFont();
        AllocFont(font, this.comboBox1,10);
    }
```

But I can't seem to alocate the font to the datagridview combobox. The combobox is already created so I don't need to create it programatically. I just need to assign the font. Any ideas? So far, I can populate the combobox items (working great) I'm new at this so if you could provide a code example so I can understand it, it would be great. This is the code i'm using to populate the list just in case you want to see it:

```
private void FillSymbolCombo()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select symbols from shopmanager.engineering_symbols;", con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sList = myReader.GetString("symbols");
                Column5.Items.Add(sList);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Here is my code in case someone else has the same problem:

```
private void loadFont()
    {
        byte[] fontArray = ERP1.Properties.Resources.engineering2;
        int dataLenght = ERP1.Properties.Resources.engineering2.Length;

        IntPtr ptrData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(dataLenght);
        Marshal.Copy(fontArray, 0, ptrData, dataLenght);

        uint cFonts = 0;
        AddFontMemResourceEx(ptrData, (uint)fontArray.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref cFonts);

        PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
        pfc.AddMemoryFont(ptrData, dataLenght);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrData);

        ff = pfc.Families[0];
        font = new Font(ff, 9f, FontStyle.Regular);

        // This is where I assign the font to the combobox in the datagridview
        Column5.DefaultCellStyle.Font = font;
    }
```

Comment: _Here is the code from someone_ Please do attribute fully!